# Hamiltonian of N spin in a vacuum

Tags: statistical-mechanics, quantum-spin

I am trying to construct a discrete partition function for N spins in a vacuum with no interaction. But I cannot figure out how to construct the Hamiltonian to be used in this function

$$
Z=\text{tr}\left(e^{-\beta \hat{H}}\right) \tag{quantum partition function}
$$

Every example that I see is a spin in a magnetic field, etc. Its never in a vacuum.

What I have so far:

The spin has the units of the action in Joules-seconds. The Hamiltonian expresses the energy of the system. So dividing the action by a time would yield the energy of the system. However this could be applied to any system not just spin. To recover some features of the spin I consider that; as the spin has a rotational symmetry, injecting a SU(2) matrix perhaps could help. I get

$$
\hat{H}= \frac{1}{t} \left[ \begin{matrix} \alpha & -\bar{\beta} \\ \beta & \bar{\alpha} \end{matrix} \right] \left[ \begin{matrix}1 \\ 0 \end{matrix} \right]
$$

Dividing by $t$ is done to obtain the correct units for an energy. This expresses a system that rotates around itself according to the SU(2) symmetry and has a constant energy over time. Maybe I'm missing something simple. Is my $\hat{H}$ even an Hamiltonian?

Comment: can you not just set the $B$-field to $0$ in the problem with the magnetic field?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Well no because the Hamiltonian then becomes zero. And the partition function of a spin is not zero. So it doesn't work.

Comment: what is the meaning of the matrix elements here?  If you have $N$ spins shouldn't you have at least an $N\times N$ matrix?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I know its wrong I'm trying to figure out to do it.

Comment: If you have non-interacting spins and no magnetic field, your Hamiltonian should be zero as the energy of the system is zero. The spins can rotate freely without any energy cost.

Comment: @Julian But then the partition function would be Z=1, and the entropy would be 0. Yet we know each spin has an entropy of $k_B \ln{2}$ as there are two possible states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the Partition function of N spins without any external field. For simplicity, I will consider spins up or down in the z-direction. A generalization to freely rotating spins is trivial.

First, as the spins are non-interacting, the Hamiltonian is simply the sum of the single spin contributions and the partition sum the product of them. Thus,
$$
Z_N = (Z_1)^N,
$$
where $Z_N$ is the partition function of $N$ spins and $Z_1$ is the partition function of a single spin system.

The one-spin Hamiltonian is
$$
\hat{H} = \frac{\mu B}{2}\sigma_z,
$$
where $B$ is the magnetic field and $\sigma_z$ is a Pauli spin matrix. In the absence of a magnetic field, the Hamiltonian is zero. This makes intuitive sense, as the energy of the system is always zero. Note, however, that $\hat H$ is the zero **matrix**. Taking the exponential of the zero matrix yields the identity matrix ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential#Properties)). Thus
$$
Z_1 = \mathrm{tr}\left(e^{-\beta\hat H}\right) = 2
$$
and your final answer is
$$
Z_N = 2^N.
$$